# Cookie Will Not Display In Alert Box

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, alert

I Can Not Get A Cookie To Display In A Alert Box Even Though The Cookie Is Set.

I Checked If The Cookie Was Set, And It Was.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
alert(var x = document.cookie;)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I Expected A Alert Box But Ended Without A Alert Box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, welcome to the world of JavaScript. I'm just going to start by pointing out there is a syntax error in your code, particularly this line:  `alert(var x = document.cookie;)`.

the `alert` method expects a parameter, which can be a variable. However, what you wrote as an input parameter to the method is `var x = document.cookie;`, which is a variable declaration. This line `var x = document.cookie;` is known as an declaration, with an assignment, basically you are declaring the variable `x` and assigning the value `document.cookie` to it. A variable declaration cannot be used as a parameter to a method.

Instead, what you are looking for is to set the variable `x` to the cookie, then display it in the `alert`, like so:

```js
document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
var x = document.cookie;
alert(x);
```